# jQuery '$(...).jScrollPane is not a function' in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

I am trying to implenment the jScrollPane jQuery plugin and I keep getting "TypeError: $(...).jScrollPane is not a function." I followed the implementation on the jScrollPane documentation but still no luck. I am using React framework.

index.html:

```
<head>
    <!-- styles needed by jScrollPane -->
    <link type="text/css" href="node_modules/jscrollpane/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <!-- latest jQuery direct from google's CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jscrollpane/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jscrollpane/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

</head>

 ...
```

I tried moving the scripts before the closing body tag as well.

index.tsx:

```
...

var $ = require("jquery");

import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import jScrollPane from 'jscrollpane';

...

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.sk-hits-grid-hit').jScrollPane();
}
```

I thought it could be because I am importing jQuery twice (in index.html and index.tsx) but taking away one did nothing. What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Check your browser's network tab to ensure the includes are loaded and not giving a 404

Comment: Under the status for jquery.jscrollpane.css and jquery.jscrollpane.min.js it says "finished" and jquery.min.js is "200 OK"